# Doing things in sequence using completion handlers

Tags: ios, swift, function, firebase, completionhandler

I have three functions that need to run in sequence as follows:

1. Gather integers from Firebase, place them into an array, and calculate the sum.  Once complete...
2. Gather a different integer value from Firebase.  Once complete...
3. The third function takes the value from function 2, and subtracts it from function 1.

I know I need to use completion handlers, but need some help with the syntax, etc.

//This first function grabs integers from Firebase and sums them up:

```
func LoadPointsCompleted(completion: @escaping(_ sumOfPointsCompleted:Int) -> Int){

    self.challengeList.removeAll()

    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    let refChallenges = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Challenges").child(userID!).queryOrdered(byChild: "Status").queryEqual(toValue: "Complete")

    refChallenges.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        //if the reference have some values
        if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {

            //clearing the list
            self.challengeList.removeAll()



            //iterating through all the values
            for Challenges in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                //getting values
                let challengeObject = Challenges.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                let Points = challengeObject?["Points"] as! Int

                //creating challenge object with model and fetched values
                let challenge = pointsModel(Points: (Points as Int?)!)

                //appending it to list
                self.challengeList.append(challenge)


                let sumOfPointsCompleted = self.challengeList.reduce(0) {$0 + $1.Points}

                let sumOfPointsCompletedString = String(sumOfPointsCompleted)
                self.Calc_Earned.text = sumOfPointsCompletedString

                completion(sumOfPointsCompleted)

            }

        }

    }

    )}
```

// This second function just grabs an integer value from another location in Firebase

```
func loadPointsRedeemed(completion: @escaping (_ Points_Redeem: Int) -> Int) {


    databaseReference = Database.database().reference()

    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

    databaseReference.child("Users").child(userID!).observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        // let Points_Earn = value?["Points_Earned"] as? String ?? ""
        let Points_Redeem = value?["Points_Redeemed"] as! Int


        // self.Points_Earned.text = Points_Earn

        let points_redeemedString = String(Points_Redeem)
        self.Points_Redeemed.text = points_redeemedString

        // let pointsRedeemedAs = Points_Redeem

        completion(Points_Redeem)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

)}
```

// This third function simply takes the values from the first two functions and subtracts them

```
 func BalanceOfPoints(){

    let a = LoadPointsCompleted()
    let b = loadPointsRedeemed()


    let balance = a - b
    let balanceString = String(balance)

    self.Points_Balance.text = balanceString

}
```

However, I get some errors in the third function "BalanceOfPoints" as follows:

Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call - insert 'completion: <(Int) -> Int>'

I have no idea if my syntax is correct when I first start the functions as per here:

```
func LoadPointsCompleted(completion: @escaping(_ sumOfPointsCompleted:Int) -> Int){
```

and...

func loadPointsRedeemed(completion: @escaping (_ Points_Redeem: Int) -> Int) {

Could someone please help?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use sequential completion handlers, go with Promise approach or Dispatch Group. Handling sequential completion handlers are messy to manage n handle errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LoadPointsCompleted` takes a closure as an argument (a completion handler)

you could either give it a `nil` completion handler

```
LoadPointsCompleted(completion: nil)
```

or give it a handler

```
LoadPointsCompleted() { sumOfPointsCompleted in

    return <#some Int#>
}
```

but your logic in `BalanceOfPoints` seems a bit off because `LoadPointsCompleted` and `loadPointsRedeemed` are being called sequentially at the same time and also do not actually return an `Int`, only the completion handler of the function does. eg `completion(sumOfPointsCompleted)` could be changed to be `let a = completion(sumOfPointsCompleted)` but im sure thats not what you were intending.

I would change the signature of both those functions to

```
func LoadPointsCompleted(completion: @escaping(_ sumOfPointsCompleted:Int) -> Void){
```

and

```
func loadPointsRedeemed(completion: @escaping (_ Points_Redeem: Int) -> Void) {
```

then in `BalanceOfPoints` do this instead

```
func BalanceOfPoints(){

    LoadPointsCompleted() { sumOfPointsCompleted in
        loadPointsRedeemed() { Points_Redeem in
            let balance = sumOfPointsCompleted - Points_Redeem
            let balanceString = String(balance)

            self.Points_Balance.text = balanceString
        }
    }
}
```

but just note that `BalanceOfPoints` in now an asynchronous function.

Not sure if step 1 and 2 in your question could be done in parallel, but seems like they could be, but as it stands in this answer they are in sequence

Comment: Hi Fonix, ok, this did work.  However, now how do I call all three functions in viewDidLoad()?

simply doing this does not work:

LoadPointsCompleted()
loadPointsRedeemed()
BalanceOfPoints()

Comment: never mind... all I need to do is call BalanceOfPoints().  It worked!  Thanks!